Is there a way to stop MAUI app from termination on encountering Unhandled Exception?
If there is a snippet in my codebase, that is not wrapped in try-catch block and throws an error. Is there a way to globally handle that in MAUI.
I have tried both
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException &
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += HandleMethod
But both these methods, are just invoked before the app crashes and are helpful only for logging. Is there any way to globally wrap the app in try-catch or handle the crash. For Android & iOS platforms.

This question is similar to: How Do You Create A Global Error Handling for a MAUI App. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
